# Rmarkdown plot and image side by side

Tags: r-markdown

I'm working on a report in R markdown.
I know there is a way to have different plots side by side, and there is also a way to have different images side by side.

But is it also possible to show a plot and an image side by side?

I have a ggplot bar graph that I would like to present next to an image of a map, it takes up too much space if I put the image below the graph.

Thanks,
Regards,
Freya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work to you. Here is the step by step, with an indication of the code between parentheses.

First, you need to load the image (`y`), by creating an object (`photo`).

Second, you create a ggplot with the image (`photo_panel`).

Finally, after creating your plot (`p1`), you use the library `cowplot` to plot a grid (`plot_grid`).

---

**`.Rmd` file:**

````
---
title: "Image + graph"
author: bttomio
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r image_graph}

y = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/AaronEckhart10TIFF.jpg"
download.file(y,'y.jpg', mode = 'wb')

library("jpeg")
photo <- readJPEG("y.jpg",native=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
photo_panel <- ggdraw() + draw_image(photo, scale = 0.8)

df <- data.frame(Years=rep(2016:2017, each=4),
                 Quarters=rep(paste0("Q", 1:4), 2),
                 Series1=seq(100, 800, 100))

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Quarters, y=Series1)) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Years, strip.position="bottom", scales="free_x") + 
  theme(panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background=element_blank(), 
        strip.placement="outside", 
        aspect.ratio=1)  # set aspect ratio

plot_grid(p1, photo_panel, ncol = 2)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks! (I try not to work during the weekends, which is why I only just now looked at your solution)

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help you :)

Comment: Does this have a problem with Plotly? I can't get it to work, it just shows a blank image

Comment: @IgnacioEstevo, not sure. Could you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61574925/13249862)?